# How to find the types for python standard library?

Tags: python, type-hinting, python-typing

I am currently trying to add type hints to my python program. However, I find the documentation for the python standard library functions does not contain any information about the types they accept and return.

E.g. [here](https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/os.path.html#os.path.dirname), there is no information what type `os.path.dirname` accepts and what type it returns. So how do I get the type information for the python standard library so that I can add type hints to my code, like this:

```
dirName: <RelevantType> = os.path.dirname(examplePath)
```

?

Comment: The semi-official standard library type hints are in [typeshed](https://github.com/python/typeshed). You shouldn't have to manually annotate the types provided by the standard library, though – type checkers already know them.

Comment: Check the documentation (specifically the Notes) as in [os.path](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.path.html) .

Comment: @MisterMiyagi Yeah but I still may need the type if I want to accept arguments of that type in a function

Comment: @PtitXav Ok that kind of answers my question and I suppose it is true during runtime. But I am not sure whether mypy will want a more specific type or not.

Comment: What editor are you using? I use pycharm. Using `ctrl+q` shows me the typehints and docstring of function/class I'm at with my cursor.

Comment: @LuckyLub: I am just using vim, so I need to manually find the types.

Comment: @AlexWaygood yes it does